# Disable DHE for AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, tls1.2, aws-application-load-balancer

We are using AWS ALB we want to disable the DHE key exchange to avoid CVE-2022-40735 
As per my findings ALB is not supported to create costume policy 
is there any other solution we can apply to mitigate CVE-2022-40735